# Android - queryPurchaseHistoryAsync Purchase List is empty on other devices

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm trying to implement the new Google Play Billing to my app, and try to retrieve my already purchased in-app product, by using `queryPurchaseHistoryAsync()` method, and the `Purchase` list always empty with 0 elemnts.

The code is working fine on my device which I purchased the item, but with my other device which has the same Google account, it returns nothing.

Also as in the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_java_kotlin#Query-recent), `queryPurchaseHistoryAsync()` should sync with Google to get the purchase history, but for some reason it does not seem to sync.

My code is:

```
BillingClient billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(getApplicationContext()).setListener(new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(int responseCode, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
        if(responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
            //Do something
        }
    }
}).build();
billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBillingSetupFinished(int responseCode) {
        if(responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
            //Response is OK and working fine
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
        //Do something
    }
});

billingClient.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP, new PurchaseHistoryResponseListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPurchaseHistoryResponse(int responseCode, List<Purchase> purchasesList) {
        if(responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
            //Always returning 0 size() of purchasesList
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There are " + purchasesList.size() + " items you've purchased.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Where exactly have I gone wrong with this code?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 13):

Did you call *queryPurchaseHistoryAsync()* after *onBillingSetupFinished()*?

It does seem you call queryPurchaseHistoryAsync() before onBillingSetupFinished() is called on your source code.

You can check the following code in [this doc](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_java_kotlin#Connect)

```
private BillingClient mBillingClient;
...
mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(mActivity).setListener(this).build();
mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingResponse int billingResponseCode) {
        if (billingResponseCode == BillingResponse.OK) {
            // The billing client is ready. You can query purchases here.

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() { }
});
```

Comment: This might be the case in the original question, but it's not the real issue. I'm absolutely positive I'm doing everything correctly yet I also have the same issue. Even on the very same device, the async method always returns an empty list.

Comment: Could you share the [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) can we check?

Answer (score 1):

To consume all the unconsumed items you can run this snippet in *onBillingSetupFinished*

```
val purchases = billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
for (purchase in purchases.purchasesList ?: emptyList()){
    val consumeParams =
        ConsumeParams.newBuilder()
            .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
            .build()
    billingClient.consumeAsync(consumeParams){ billingResultAfterConsumed , string ->
        //Talk to your server / local database to deliver the consumable to the user
    }
}
```

Comment: After consume I am not talking to the server. But why the billingClient.queryPurchase not shows the result for me? Initially it shows the result but after some time If i navigate to the app, it again shows the purchase item.